# choose resources from app language (not system language)

Tags: android, android-resources

My android app has its own language, which can be not equal with device system language. For ex - MyApp has 'ru' language, but phone has 'en' lang. 
Can i do smth with app to take my app language locale resources, not by system language?

PS - my app language I changing by this code:

```
public static void setLocale(String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        SvoApplication.getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                                                                       SvoApplication.getContext()
                                                                                     .getResources()
                                                                                     .getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferencesManager.setCurrentLanguage(language);
    }
```

And all data that have taken from db is localized by sharedPref value of app language

PPS - i understand that i must use strings-en.xml/strings-ru.xml or etc. And it worked when i change my app lang. But when i rotate screen for example - all resources are changing to what system default language is

Comment: Have a look at the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just override the **onConfigurationChanged** method in your class which extends **Application.class**. And set the **config.locale** same as above

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
        /*here code to set locale*/
}
```

and now it will work fine, when you rotate your screen.

Comment: i'll test it and write you about results! thnks!